# How do you put text below other text?

Tags: math, latex

I need to write the expression meaning *optimize over the parameter set*. I think I should write something like

```
$\arg \max_{\substack{w \\ \phi}} f(w,\phi)$
```

but this puts the subscript below at the right of \max and I'd like to put those subindexes below and centered on the max word.

Which command should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using the equation in 'inline mode' as above, that is the expected (and desired) behavior, as it respects the line height.  See below if you want to use a display equation instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried display mode math instead of text mode math. That is, try either:

```
$\displaystyle\arg \max_{\substack{w \\ \phi}} f(w,\phi)$
```

Or try:

```
\[ \arg \max_{\substack{w \\ \phi}} f(w,\phi) \]
```

Comment: The displaystyle thing for the in-line mode is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

See: http://www.breakthru.altervista.org/?p=27

using

```
\underset{x}{\operatorname{argmax}}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$\arg \max\limits_{\substack{w\\ \phi}} f(w,\phi)$
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this statement. It will surely work. Update the parameters as per your requirement :

max┬(0≤x≤1)⁡〖xe^(-x^2 ) 〗